# SQL Query - GROUP BY , PARTITION BY

Tags: sql

This is my first post and I am new to SQL

I have a table like

```
H     Amount    Count      ID 

h1      2         1         x
h2      3         2         x
h3      5         3         x
h1      3         3         x
h1      1         5         y
h2      3         2         x
h3      1         1         x
h3      2         3         y
h2      5         5         y
```

and I want SUM(Amount*Count) of each H group based on id / Total SUM(Amount*Count) in that H group

i.e

```
H     value       ID

h1     11/16       x                     value =  (2*1+3*3)/2*1+3*3+1*5 
h1      5/16       y                     value =   1*5/ 2*1+3*3+1*5 
h2      12/37      x 
h2      25/37      y 
h3      16/22      x 
h3       6/22      y
```

My aim is  to group by H and then on EACH GROUP I have to do  - Sum(average*count) Over(partition by ID) / Sum(average*count)

but I am not able to write such query can you guys please help me.
 And sorry about the formatting
 Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT t2.h, t1.value1/t2.value2, t1.id  
FROM 
     (SELECT sum(value) as value1, id  from table
      group by id) as t1, 
     (SELECT sum(value) as value2, h  from table
      group by h) as t2
WHERE t1.h = t2.h
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy answer is to use an inner query like so:

```
SELECT SUM(Amount * Count), (SELECT SUM(Amount * Count) FROM table AS t2 WHERE t2.H = t1.H)
FROM table AS t1
GROUP BY H, ID
```

This essentially refers to the same table as both `t1` and `t2` for two different queries.

However, the specific database management system you're using (MySQL, Microsoft SQL Server, sqlite, whatever) may have a built-in function to handle this sort of thing. You should look into what your DBMS offers (or tag your question here with a specific platform).

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is get the dividend value (sum of amount*count per `h -> id` group) and join the divisor value (sum of amount*count per `h` group) in another subselect:

```
SELECT 
    a.h, a.id, a.dividend / b.divisor AS value
FROM
(
    SELECT h, id, SUM(amount*count) AS dividend
    FROM tbl
    GROUP BY h, id
) a 
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT h, SUM(amount*count) AS divisor
    FROM tbl
    GROUP BY h
) b ON a.h = b.h
```